# Issue with the AutoDesk Forge Design Automation API

Tags: pdf, autocad, autodesk-forge, dwg, autodesk-designautomation

I tried using [this](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/tutorials/convert-dwg-to-pdf/) tutorial, to convert [this](https://dl5.volafile.net/get/QH1A-3VR4ubU/1128.dwg) dwg to pdf, but it just gave me an empty [pdf](https://dl6.volafile.io/get/QH3-o1nWdRS0/result%20(3).pdf).

Convertors online are not helping because the pdf is just an image of the drawing, same is happening when exporting as pdf from Autocad. Is there any way to preserve the text when exporting as pdf or some other format?

Comment: From an answer given below, this appears to be unreproducible. I shall try to vote to close, as it is not likely to be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious to learn what you tried from AutoCAD. Here is a picture of your dwg plotted to pdf from Autocad using EXPORTOPDF.

[image: Plotted to PDF from Autocad]

Now let me continue my research with the use of Design Automation. We might have some problem with the PlotToPdf activity but let me get back to you about it.

Answer (score 0):

When I use your drawing I get PDF that isn't empty: it has a rectangle in the upper left corner. This drawing has 2 layouts Layout1 has the rectangle and Layout2 has lots of interesting stuff (that's the stuff that Jaime shows above)

Do you want that? If so you could simply delete Layout1 and the service would produce the right result for you.

BTW, I have some more detailed tutorials here:
https://github.com/szilvaa/acadio-tutorials